# nhibernate mapping by code identity not insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I'm using nhibernate 5,1,1. Mapping by code
when you add an entry, you send 2 requests

select max (id) From Bred

insert Into Bred (Id, Name, PetType) valuses ({value of max (id)}, text, 1)

I need the field id not to be sent in the insert request and there was no first request. Id auto increment
How can I do that?

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ин.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Дата добавления
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DateTime DateInsert { get; set; }
}    

public abstract class BaseMapping<T> : ClassMapping<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected BaseMapping(string nameTabel)
    {
        this.Table(nameTabel);
        this.Id(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Generator(Generators.Increment);
            map.Column("\"Id\"");

        });
        this.Property(x => x.DateInsert, x =>
        {
            x.Column("\"DateInsert\"");
            x.Insert(false);
            x.Update(false);

        });
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Справочник пород
/// </summary>
public class Breed : BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Название
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Тип животных 
    /// </summary>
    public virtual PetType PetType { get; set; }
}

public class BreedMap : BaseMapping<Breed>
{
    public BreedMap() : base("\"Breed\"")
    {
        this.Property(x => x.Name, x => x.Column("\"Name\""));
        this.Property(x => x.PetType, x => x.Column("\"PetType\""));
    }
}
```

Comment: doing this "select max (id) From Bred" may not give you the next id because someone may have already taken it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the field id not to be sent in the insert request and there was no first request...

In case that our DB is supporting IDENTITY *(auto increment on DB side)*, we should not use `Increment`, but **`Native`** setting *(or `Identity`)*

```
//map.Generator(Generators.Increment);
map.Generator(Generators.Native);
```

Check the doc for detailed explanation

#### [5.1.5.1. generator](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator)

small extract

> `increment`
>
> generates identifiers of any integral type that are unique only when
>   no other process is inserting data into the same table. Do not use in
>   a cluster.
>
> ...
>
> `native/identity`
>
> supports identity columns in DB2, MySQL, MS SQL Server and Sybase.
>   The identifier returned by the database is converted to the property
>   type using Convert.ChangeType. Any integral property type is thus
>   supported.
>
> ...